# How to run a app in cmd when the path contain (blank and number) not only blank

Tags: java, cmd, mysql

1. failure

```html
String mysql = "C:/Progra~1/Apache~1/Tomcat~1/a.exe";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + mysql);
```

The real path is C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\a.exe

1. success

```html
String mysql = "C:/Progra~1/Apache~1/a.exe";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + mysql);
```

The real path is C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\a.exe

why the first don't work?

Comment: Are you sure the short name for "tomcat 6.0" is tomcat~1 ?

Comment: i'm not sure ,but the length shuld be 8. if the file don't has the version number,it will word. i don't know the reason.

Comment: i don't know the short name for like "aa 2.0"、"tomcat 6.0",but i know the short name for like "Program Files".

Comment: Thank you everyone! the problem has sloved when i saw http://mackaz.de/394.

Comment: btw, dir /x shows shortnames, theres no reason for not knowing

Comment: The script in the link you gave (mackaz.de/394) is very fragile: it will break very easily.  Using the %~sI operator is certainly one (potentially) thing you can learn from the script, but otherwise I wouldn't recommend using it.

Answer (score 1):

As some readers have pointed out, likely your first example did not work because you had the 8.3 name incorrect.  Alternatively, it makes more sense to use the "long" names:

```
String mysql = "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/a.exe";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"" + mysql + "\"");
```